# alter serach box position in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, search

Please visit http://newtrendzonline.com/boards/

you can see background-box for search box,

How to move the Background-box to right, near basket ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove from the class `.form-search` this:

```
position: absolute; 
top: 100px; 
left: 600px;
```

Then on `.link-bottom, .em-top-search` add a `margin-left: 375px`. (or something around that)

Comment: is above changes will cause an issue with resolution ? `fix top` and `fix left`

Comment: @liyakat. I have no idea. CSS is not my strongest point. I just used played with firebug to position the element.

Comment: sorry to interrupt you, but i am not sure about this. just thinking in mind.

Comment: @liyakat. I'm not 100% sure either. if the OP says it didn't work I will delete this. In the meantime, if you think this is wrong  feel free to downvote it. This is how stackexchange should work.

Comment: i am not saying that you are wrong.you could be right.+1 for me to have good thought and quick solution. rather then my long changes. :(. And i have also checked my view in firebug to set searchbox in beside cart.

Comment: @liyakat. Don't +1 if you don't know for sure that this is right.

Comment: you are right marius.if site is not depends on resolution.then wan't any issue with your solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

2 modifications

- in your `theme.css.php` (odd name), at line 127, applied to class `.form-search`, change your `left:150px;` to `left:0;` (or simply remove it)
- in the same file, line 114, applied to class `.em-top-search`, change your `float:left;` to `float:right;`

you might want then your search on the left side of your cart. 
 - simply swap in your template the `<div class="em-top-search">` with `<div class="top-cart-inner" id="click">`

I let you polish the round corners afterwards.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

you have to change position for search box div

it should be like below

```
<div id="click" class="top-cart-inner">
    <div id="link-top-cart" class="link-top-cart">
        <p><a class="top-link-cart" id="topcartlink" href="http://newtrendzonline.com/boards/index.php/checkout/cart/"><span class="icon top-cart"></span><span class="qty-top-cart"> 0</span></a></p>
    </div>

    <div style="display: none;" id="top_cart" class="top-cart-content">
                <div class="block block-cart-top">
            <div class="top-icon"></div>
            <div class="block-content">
               <p class="empty">You have no items in your shopping cart.</p>
                            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**Add Searchbox here after above div**

```
<div class="em-top-search" style="float:right; margin-right:10px;"><form method="get" action="http://newtrendzonline.com/boards/index.php/catalogsearch/result/" id="search_mini_form">    
    <div class="form-search">        
        <div class="input-search">
            <div class="input-cate input_cat">

            </div>
            <div class="input-form-search">
                <input type="text" maxlength="128" class="input-text" value="" name="q" id="search" autocomplete="off">
                <button class="button" title="Search" type="submit"><span><span>Search</span></span></button>
                <div class="search-autocomplete" id="search_autocomplete" style="display: none;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        //&amp;amp;lt;![CDATA[
            var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', 'Search entire store here...');
            searchForm.initAutocomplete('http://newtrendzonline.com/boards/index.php/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/', 'search_autocomplete');
        //]]&amp;amp;gt;
        </script>
    </div>
</form>                    </div>
```

Add above inline css like

```
style="float:right; margin-right:10px;" to  `class="em-top-search"` in your css.
```

hope this will sure solve help you.